# Azure AD B2B API failing for sovereign cloud

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

I am using Azure AD B2B Invitation API to invite external users in my tenant. Its working perfectly but recently for one external domain its failing and the error message is:

> "Code: BadRequest\r\nMessage: You're trying to invite a user whose Azure AD account is in a sovereign cloud. To collaborate with this user, ask the user for another email address or create a member user account for the user in your Azure AD directory.\r\n\r...

Can somebody please explain what is this sovereign cloud? I know that user is from Germany so does this cloud part of Office 365 Germany or Office 365 Government? And B2B collaboration feature is not possible with those tenants? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This user belongs to Office 365 Germany cloud. The data from different cloud (Azure cloud and national cloud) are not interoperable. The national cloud are managed by specific country(The customer data stays in that country). That's why you encountered that error message.

The workaround:

> ask the user for another email address or create a member user account
>   for the user in your Azure AD directory

Answer (score -1):

Cross-sovereign B2B is now possible (4 years later)!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/cross-cloud-settings

When Azure AD organizations in separate Microsoft Azure clouds need to collaborate, they can use Microsoft cloud settings to enable Azure AD B2B collaboration. B2B collaboration is available between the following global and sovereign Microsoft Azure clouds:

- Microsoft Azure commercial cloud and Microsoft Azure Government
- Microsoft Azure commercial cloud and Microsoft Azure operated by 21Vianet

To set up B2B collaboration between partner organizations in different Microsoft Azure clouds, each partner mutually agrees to configure B2B collaboration with each other. In each organization, an admin completes the following steps:

1. Configures their Microsoft cloud settings to enable collaboration with the partner's cloud.
2. Uses the partner's tenant ID to find and add the partner to their organizational settings.
3. Configures their inbound and outbound settings for the partner organization. The admin can either apply the default settings or configure specific settings for the partner.
4. After each organization has completed these steps, Azure AD B2B collaboration between the organizations is enabled.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers) See also: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/525172)

Comment: Added most relevant information from linked documentation.